# Trouble creating a polygon path

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble creating a polygon path for a physicsbody. I'm loading a plist that contains an array of points for the path.

In the image below I have blue dots visualising where the points from the plist are located to create the path. You can also see the outline around the node from `.showsPhysics = true`. The green dots, however, visualise collisions between the player and the node. I should **not** be colliding where the green dots are appearing as you can tell by the nodes physicsbody in the second image.

[image]

Here is what it looks like with just `.showsPhysics = true`

[image]

Now I'm fairly certain this problem is arising from the `polygon.move(...` part because when I change the CGPoint from the first point in the plist to a different point not contained in the plist, then the problem go away, but this isn't practical for other nodes and plists.

```
let polygon = CGMutablePath()

for points in hull {
    let point = CGPointFromString(points)
    let adjustedPoint = CGPoint(x: point.x / sizeRatio, y: point.y / sizeRatio)

    if polygon.isEmpty {
        polygon.move(to: adjustedPoint)
    }
    else {
        polygon.addLine(to: adjustedPoint)
    }
}

polygon.closeSubpath()
```

Here's a photo of when I change `polygon.move(to: adjustedPoint)` to `polygon.move(to:CGPoint.zero)` which might be of some help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry.. what exactly is the problem here...? The green dots or something?

Comment: I'm colliding with an invisible line shown by the green dots. This line doesn't appear with `showsPhysics` as I've shown above. However when I change `polygon.move(to: adjustedPoint)` to `polygon.move(to:CGPoint.zero)` the invisible line disappears and I'm able to collide with the node's physicsbody as expected.

Comment: Hmmmmm I'm struggling with this one.. can you post a sample project for us to play with?

Comment: Does your path loop back to the starting point? or does your path start at the top and end at the bottom?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It begins at the first point and loops around to the last point. I have just tried looping back to the first point but the problem still persists. No idea why I don't get problems with any of the other obstacle physicbodies. Maybe it's just a problem with Spritekit and the iOS I'm using?

Comment: It has to do with the concave shape

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I managed to fix this. No idea why but I was using an array of points from `fixture.hull` instead of `fixture.polygons`...